# Find div id in string and delete the whole div

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, find

I have a string with some DOM HTML saved inside, among which a div with static id="myId", which has no innerHTML but has dynamic width value set.

Example:

```
myString = "<div class="class">blahblah</div><div id="myId" width="42.584px"></div>"
```

How can I create a new identical string cutting off the whole `<div id="myId" width="42.584px"></div>`? The problem is that `width=""` value changes all the time so I can't do a `.replace`.

the HTML saved in the string, looks something like this (and number of divs can vary, but obviously only one has the `myId` div mentioned):

```
<div id="firstId"></div>
<div id="div0" class="div-class">
<span class="" onclick="clickFunctionTwo()">text div 0</span>
<span class="" id="fasdf"></span>
<span id="btnClose"><img src="close.svg" class="" onclick="clickFunction()"></span>
<div id="myId" class="" style="width: 59.5312px;"></div>
</div>
<div id="div1" class="div-class">
<span class="" onclick="clickFunctionTwo()">text div 1</span>
<span class="" id="eyuacv"></span>
<span id="btnClose"><img src="close.svg" class="" onclick="clickFunction()"></span>
</div>
<div contenteditable="true" id="lastId" style="height:18px;" onkeydown="myFunction()"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a jQuery element from that string, remove the `#myID` div then grab the new HTML:

```js
var myString = `
  <div id="firstId"></div>
  <div id="div0" class="div-class">
    <span class="" onclick="clickFunctionTwo()">text div 0</span>
    <span class="" id="fasdf"></span>
    <span id="btnClose"><img src="close.svg" class="" onclick="clickFunction()"></span>
    <div id="myId" class="" style="width: 59.5312px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="div1" class="div-class">
    <span class="" onclick="clickFunctionTwo()">text div 1</span>
    <span class="" id="eyuacv"></span>
    <span id="btnClose"><img src="close.svg" class="" onclick="clickFunction()"></span>
  </div>
  <div contenteditable="true" id="lastId" style="height:18px;" onkeydown="myFunction()"></div>`;

var myNewString = $('<div>').append(myString).find('#myId').remove().end().html();

console.log(myNewString);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Do you know if this throw an error and breaks the js file in case the div #myId doesn't exist? or it's just fine to leave it without any check?

Comment: @notsure It should be fine, `.remove` will just do nothing in that case.

Comment: @notsure Not working for you? Noticed you unchecked the answer.

Comment: I was gonna reply indeed, i noticed it actually returns me only a first <div id="firstDiv"></div>  present in the string, before using your code it logs the whole thing so must be it, but i'm not sure why, in the snippet here the logic works fine. i'll edit with a more in depth example of my string html

Comment: I've added the full html example that's being saved in the string, hope it helps you understand where can be the issue, because i'm trying but have no clue (maybe the outerHtml conflict with brakets "" ?)

Comment: @notsure Updated with full HTML from your edited question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try do build that string in another way,like:

```
var myArray = [
  "<div class="class">blahblah</div>",
  "<div id="myId" width="42.584px"></div>"
]
```

And you can build the string with:

```
var myString = myArray.join("")
```

And make the changes on myArray[0...n]. So removing a single array position its like removing a div.